# How to get text of first element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

I am trying to get the text in the first `td` in the parent `tr` which the clicked `span` element is located.

I thought the following would work, but it returns text in all `td` elements of the given `tr`.  How do I do this without doing something like `$t.closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).text()`?

http://jsfiddle.net/9dh7pz73/3/

```
$("table span").click(function(){
    var $t=$(this);
    console.log($t.closest('tr'),$t.closest('tr').first('td').text());
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td><span>xxx</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td><span>xxx</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td><span>xxx</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  You are right!  I've since updated.  Was lazy and thought I forked an existing similar jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to target the first `<td>` element when a specific span is clicked, you could just wire up an event handler to pick up the click and then find the first `<td>` via the `td:first` selector:

```
$('table span').click(function(){
    // This will find the closest <tr> and then the first <td> element that appears within
    console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text());  
});
```

**Example**

[image]

```js
$('table span').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><span>xxx</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><span>xxx</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><span>xxx</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `first()` method doesn't take a selector. Instead you could do `find('td:first')`, like this:

```js
$("table span").click(function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    console.log($t.closest('tr').find('td:first').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td><span>xxx</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td><span>xxx</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td><span>xxx</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```